# Rails & Carrierwave: How to output img_tag in different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave

I would like to know how I can output an img_tag on a foreign controller/view. I have generated a Carrierwave uploader in Rails and mounted it to a particular model. Now I want to access the uploaded images in views of different controllers. All I get is a Output like `/images/%23%3CImage::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004a503a8%3E`.

In the Image model an uploader is mounted with

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

I tried to get the `img_path` or to create an `img_tag` but I won't get a working result. For example I am doing it like this:

```
<div class="parallax-container">
  <% @image = Image.where(category: 'Parallax', id: :id) %>
  <div class="parallax"><%= image_path(@image) %></div>
</div>
```

The `debug params` output shows me that my controller is `games` and for example the `id:` is 1 on a particular page. So even if I change the where hash and tell it to use `id: '1'` I won't get a proper image path.

If I instead use `<%= image_tag(@image) %>` the same ActiveRecord-Relation-Output is created for the SRC and ALT parameter.

And when I try to use `<%= image_tag @image.img_url %>` I am told that `img_url` is an undefined method.

Games and Images are related in that way, that a game has many images and an image belongs to a game.

I also tried to add an instance variable to the games show controller but it does not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) method return an array of records `ActiveRecord_Relation`. If you have an `id` of the record which you need, you should use [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find) method.

```
<% @image = Image.where(category: 'Parallax').find(id_of_the_record) %>
```

Also you can find image by the category with the same `find` method:

```
<% @image = Image.find_by(category: 'Parallax') %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right, `where` always offers an array of elements, even if it is only one. :) Now that I know that, I can access the image. Hooray.